# .filter() a datastore query for one parameter with multiple values

Tags: filter, google-cloud-datastore

so i have list of users 
`user_list = [user_object_1,user_object_2,user_object_3]`

users created artifacts and ownership was assigned like this `user = db.ReferenceProperty(Users, collection_name='artifacts')`

so now I need to query for 10 most recent artifacts created by any of these three users. My wild guess was to do it like this:

`listings = classes.ListItems.all().filter('user=',user_list).order('-created').run(offset=offset, limit=10)`

But as I expected: `BadValueError: Filtering on lists is not supported`

making a query for each user, fetching all artifacts, putting them all in one list, ordering by `created` and dumping anything outside top10 feels like a waste of resource.

How do i do it properly? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it `artifacts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Artifacts WHERE user IN :1", user_key_list)`